# Python indentation issue: Expected an indentation block

Tags: python, django

```
def process_health_case(request):
    about = request.POST['about']
    details = request.POST['narrative_text']
    image=request.FILES['image_scan']
    connection = Connection('mongodb://sbose78:PASSWORD@staff.mongohq.com:10068/BOSE')
    if images:
        db=connection['BOSE']
        fs=gridfs.GridFS(db)
        fs.put(image,filename="image_scan2")
    else:
        #nothing
    return render_to_response('home/new_narrative.html',{ }, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

I'm getting

```
expected an indented block (views.py, line 41)
```

And line 41 is the last line.

Where am I wrong?

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't use a comment as an empty statement, you should use [`pass`](http://docs.python.org/release/2.5.2/ref/pass.html) if you want to have an explicit else that does nothing.

```
if images:
    db=connection['BOSE']
    fs=gridfs.GridFS(db)
    fs.put(image,filename="image_scan2")
else:
    pass
return ....
```

Since there's no statement, just a comment in the `else` in your code, python thinks the `return` is supposed to be the content of the `else` and gives an intentation error.

Comment: Worked!Thank you so much Joachim! :)

Comment: Of course the else statement is completely unnecessary here anyway. If all you're doing is having `pass`, you should just leave out the whole clause.